# TensorRT installation for tensorflow GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I wanted to install tensorflow gpu but I got the following error:

```
(tfGPU) tensorflow@TihamiTahmid:/mnt/c/Users/jisha$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2023-03-30 02:52:03.368980: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-03-30 02:52:03.543056: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-30 02:52:04.581037: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-03-30 02:52:05.829507: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-03-30 02:52:05.941579: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1956] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Then I installed TensorRT using this: [NVIDIA Deep Learning TensorRT Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html)

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorrt
```

It didn't help either. Also, I don't know why I see internal error in my GPU!

[image]

Comment: TensorRT is not required for GPU support, so you are following a red herring...

Comment: Hi @ForestGump, Could you please refer to this [TF Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) official link and verify if you have followed all the given instructions and Hardware/Software requirements to install tensorflow with GPU support as per your system OS. Also please ensure that you have installed the correct version of CUDA and cuDNN as mentioned in this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and set the path accordingly. Let us know if the issue still persists.